# <c:url var = "" value="" > functions works fine, but IntelliJ still see as an error(red). Solution?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl, taglib

I have 2 functions which are Update and Delete. They work fine when I debug or run actual code, but IntelliJ shows these two paths as an error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, I have tried IntelliJ's own suggestion child tag, but it didn't work as well.

[image]

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches | mark first two checkboxes | Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: If the problem remains please prepare and provide a small project sample and contact IntelliJ IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new .

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I did It didn't work, Have sent the request. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug in IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218945/JSTL-url-Can-not-resolve-servlet), please follow it for updates.